# "This app can only access the photos you select" on emulator but not on physical device

Tags: android

I have several Android apps I am testing. When I run them in the emulator and the app tries to use a photo I get the dialog below "This app can only access the photos you select" and there is no way I can see for me to select a photo.

[image]

However, when I run the same app on a physical phone brings up my Photos and I can select one.

Is there a way to get the emulator to access photos? I assume there is some special Setting or permissions I have to set???

Comment: Do u have image files available on emulator ? there is no special setting on emulator..
Add few images and they should appear in the selection modal ..

Comment: Yes, I used the emulator camera to take some photos and they appeared, thanks! This is confusing because I also run the google photos app and there are a lot of photos there, but those do NOT appear.

Comment: Thats probably because Google photos images do not have a local copy at the moment. try downloading one and it should show for selection .

Answer (score 0):

The answer, from @ADM, is that the photos have to be on the device.

So, when it says "This app can only access the photos you select" what it really means is "This app can only access the photos **on your device**", not your photos (aka google photos).

One can go to the google photos app and Download specific photos to the device. They will then appear in this dialog.